# Java Swing getToolkit and custom cursor strange behavior

Tags: java, swing, mouse-cursor

I am creating custom cursors in my Netbeans Java Swing app. For example, where 'cursorImage' is an image file on disk, I create my default cursor like so:

```
Cursor defaultCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(cursorImage, hotspot, name);
```

Once I starting using custom cursors, my application started exhibiting very strange bugs that I cannot even explain. Through troubleshooting, I found the following code to be the problem. This code is related to my app being a Netbeans SingleFrameApplication.

```
Toolkit toolkit = MyApp.getApplication().getMainView().getRootPane()
.getToolkit().getDefaultToolkit();
```

The code exists in a simple non-GUI POJO class called CursorController.

I replaced it by this code:

```
Component c = new JButton("getToolkit");
Toolkit toolkit = c.getToolkit();
```

I don't even display the button anywhere. But the bugs are gone now.

The problem is that I do not understand the problem or why it is (apparently) resolved now. I'm not very confident that I have solved it the right way. I shouldn't really create a button just to get the toolkit, right?

Comment: Well perhaps it's a difference between which toolkit you're using. In the problematic code, you're using `getToolkit().getDefaultToolkit()`, whereas with your button you're using just `getToolkit()`.

Comment: I see your previous post, there are some way how to create/replace Cursor (came from Native OS), but looks very ugly, can you please to post http://sscce.org/, no idea what you are tried, and that nothing relevant with IDE :-)

Comment: @Shakedown - thanks. maybe it is just as simple as: getToolkit().getDefaultToolkit() vs. getToolkit(). I'll test that tomorrow.

Comment: I take it by the three years of silence that it *was* simply a matter of using `getToolkit()` vs. `getDefaultToolkit()`?